# How to establish requisite ordering relationships between salt state files(.sls)?

Tags: salt-stack

I have been working on puppet to salt migration of nginx module with manifest files: `init.pp, package.pp, conf.pp and service.pp`. The `init.pp` file contains below lines:

init.pp:

```
class nginx {
  class {'nginx::package': } ->
  class {'nginx::conf': } ->
  class {'nginx::service': }
}
```

I was able to implement order of execution with `->` between manifest files.

So for salt, I tried the below to implement order of execution for `.sls` files as shown below but didn't work during run time.

init.sls:

```
include:
  - package.sls
  - conf.sls
  - service.sls
```

In case of salt I know it allows ordering/relationships between states, but can someone suggest me on how to implement order of execution between salt state files (`package.sls, conf.sls and service.sls`) ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to define an ordering between files, but there is a way to make a state depend on an entire file:

```yaml
mystate:
  test.nop:
    - require:
      - sls: package
```

https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/states/requisites.html#require-sls-file

If `service.sls` depends on states in `conf.sls` then those relationships should be defined in those two files. They cannot sensibly be defined in a separate file.

Even better would be to only add dependencies between the specific states that need them, rather than every state in a file. An example `service.sls`:

```yaml
include:
  - package.sls
  - conf.sls

nginx:
  service.running:
    - enabled: true
    - reload: true
    - require:
      - pkg: nginx
    - watch:
      - file: /etc/nginx/*
```

Or in this particular case, just don't split them up.